# Attach log files to email notifications in teamcity

Tags: attachment, teamcity-8.0, email-notifications

I am trying to call test automation scripts(ranorex) at the end of each development build in Teamcity which is working ok.

I am sending email notification at the end of test automation, but I dont know how to attach the log file to email notifications from agent's side as I dont have access to teamcity server file system.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible to specify an attachment to be sent togehter with the e-mail.

Ranorex userCode:

```
using Ranorex.Core.Reporting;  

string RepName = TestReport.ReportEnvironment.ReportName;     
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;  
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(RepName + ".html");  
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Probably your implementation is somewhat different and to get this working you'll find all the required information from here:   http://www.ranorex.com/forum/send-mail-module-t2356.html